# Exchanges/queues access permissions in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging

I'm writing a mobile application and considering **RabbitMQ** for **user-to-user messaging**. As far as I understand, it's possible for each client to listen on it's unique queue (named, say, after user id) and message to other clients by means of publishing to their queues. But I'm worried that such model is unreliable as nasty clients may, say, read from someone else's queue thus disrupting the whole scheme.

Is there a way to impose basic read-write permissions on RabbitMQ queues/exchanges thus providing security? Or am I getting the whole concept wrong and peer-to-peer communication just isn't what the thing is designed for?

Answer (score 3):

[Access control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) is implemented in RabbitMQ. If you want user U0 to have only read access to queue Q0, you can set U0 read permission to `^QO$`. If you want finer control over users permissions, you'll have to implement this in your application, server-side.

Yet, I'd say that your design doesn't scale well. Although there isn't any hardcoded limit for the number of queues and exchanges you can delcare, you should keep this number quite reasonable since it's a bit resource-intensive. 1 million users would mean 1 million queue/exchange processes and possibly 1 million opened sockets if each user is consuming its queue. Not sure a single host would handle this properly.

For a messaging app, I would rather recommend you use any persistent database. RabbitMQ is not really suited for this kind of use-cases.